# My for loop keeps looping and causes the program to crash

Tags: c++, for-loop, crash

I'm trying to make a program that will receive a string and output an uppercase version of that. My code works, however once it loops through the string and changes it, it immediately crashes and I'm not completely sure why. Here are my two pieces of code.

```
/*This program is to intended to receive a string and return a version of it in all upper case*/    
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <locale>
 using namespace std;

 string toUpper ( string str)
  {     
    cout <<"\n";    //Puts spaces between the input and output

    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++;)
    std::cout << std::toupper(str[i]);   //A loop which goes through each digit of the    string
    break;

    cout <<"\n\n";   //Creates spaces after the output
    return str;
  }

/*This program calls a function to make a string in upper case*/
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <locale>
 #include "toUpper1.h" //Calls the header file which contains the loop      
 using namespace std; 

int main () 
 {  
    cout<<"\nPlease type in a word\n\n";

    string input;   //Creates a variable of cin that can be used in the toUpper command 
    cin>>input; //Makes a user input command part of the declared variable 

    cout<<toUpper(input);       //The command that causes the user input string to be transformed into upper case   
    return 0;   
 }
```

Comment: use std:endl in C++, the break statement you have does nothing, whats the error your getting?

Comment: Is this your actual code? The only thing I see wrong is the `break;` statement.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)`

Comment: This isn't even vlad _[sic]_ C++

Comment: I'm not getting an error, just the program running then crashing. And it is, but the break doesn't seem to cause the crash as once it's removed it is still crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make string to uppercase using code bellow

Boost string algorithms:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <string>

std::string str = "Hello World";

boost::to_upper(str);

std::string newstr = boost::to_upper_copy("Hello World");
```

Or use like this

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::string str = "Hello World";
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(),str.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the function without returning anything. Use {} to close for loops if you want to use break

> prog.cpp:16:5: error: break statement not within loop or switch
>        break;

Also your for loop has an extra ; at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout` and `std::toupper` are useless as you are already including `namespace std;`
and why are you using `break;`? there is no need of it. 
just write

```
for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
    cout << toupper(str[i]);
```

Remove break;

Comment: I tried those two lines and removed break but it's still crashing. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3267493 yes, you are overflowing the memory. You have defined none. Look the edited variant, please.

Answer (score 0):

You are not transforming the string, you are outputting its transformation in the function.

instead of

```
std::cout << std::toupper(str[i]);
```

use

```
str[i]=std::toupper(str[i]);
```

And move all printing out of the function. Changing the string doesn't include printing!

Notice the @bbdude95 answer, too.

### edit

Instead of

```
cout<<"\nPlease type in a word\n\n";
string input;   //Creates a variable of cin that can be used in the toUpper command 
cin>>input;
```

use

```
char input[256]; 
cout << "Please type in a word:\n>";
cin.getline( input, 256, '\n' );
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the line to that, yet I'm still getting a crash. It seems to me that the function is causing it to go through the loop indefinitely but that may not be right. I removed the two lines that produced spaces, yet it's still crashing.

Any other ideas of what it could be?

Comment: @user3267493 you have problems with memory area. You have set none of it. Look the edited variant.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 using namespace std; 


 string toUpper ( string str)
  {     
    cout <<"\n";    //Puts spaces between the input and output

    for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        str[i] = std::toupper(str[i]);   //A loop which goes through each digit of the    string
    //break;

    cout <<"\n\n";   //Creates spaces after the output
  return str;
  }

int main () 
 {  
    cout<<"\nPlease type in a word\n\n";

    string input;   //Creates a variable of cin that can be used in the toUpper command 
    cin>>input; //Makes a user input command part of the declared variable 

           //The command that causes the user input string to be transformed into uppe case   

    cout << toUpper(input);

   cout << std::endl << "The original string is" << input << std::endl;

   return 0;   
 }
```

EDIT: Note that keeping the function signature as above (`string toUpper ( string str)`, as were required), we are making some extra string copies, and, most important: we are NOT modifying the original string (excute the code and see the result of last `cout`.

Comment: I originally used a void loop and it worked perfectly fine with no crashes but for the assignment we can't use a void loop and must start the function with:

   `string toUpper( string )`